# Better way of applying css-modules to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-modules

I'm using css-modules with AngularJS 1.5 components now. The stack is `webpack` + `css-loader?modules=true` + `angular 1.5 components` + `pug`.

Currently I have to do the following steps to use css modules in my pug template.

```
// my-component.js

import template from 'my-component.pug';
import styles from 'my-component.css';

class MyComponent {
    constructor($element) {
        $element.addClass('myComponent');        // ------ (1)
        this.styles = styles;                    // ------ (2)
    }
}

angular.module(name, deps)
    .component('my-component', {
        controller: MyComponent,
        template: template,
    });

// my-component.pug
div(class={{ ::$ctrl.styles.fooBar }}) FooBar    // ----- (3)

// my-component.css
.myComponent { background: green; }
.fooBar { color: red; }
```

There are two problems:

1. Every component has to inject `$element` and set its class name manually. The reason for doing this is, AngularJS component tag itself exists in the result HTML without any classes, which makes CSS difficult. For example, if I use `MyComponent` above like this:

   ```
   <div>
     <my-component></my-component>
   </div>
   ```

   it will generate the following HTML:

   ```
   <div>
     <my-component>
       <div class="my-component__fooBar__3B2xz">FooBar</div>
     </my-component>
   </div>
   ```

   Compared to ReactJS, `<my-component>` in above result HTML is an extra, sometimes it makes CSS difficult to write.
   So my solution is (1), to add a class to it.
2. The class in template is too long (3). I know it is the correct way to reference `$ctrl.styles.fooBar` but this is way too long.

My ideal solution would be like this:

```
// my-component.js
angular.module(name, deps)
    .component('my-component', {
        controller: MyComponent,
        template: template,
        styles: styles,
    });

// my-component.css
div(css-class="fooBar") FooBar
```

The idea is to:

1. make `angular.module().component` support an extra `styles` attribute, which will automatically do (2) `this.styles = styles;` in the controller, and apply (1) `$element.addClass()` as well.
2. directive `css-class` to apply `$ctrl.styles` to element.

My question is, I have no idea how to implement idea 1 above (2 is easy). I appreciate if anyone could share some light on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with a solution which I don't quite satisfy with.

Angular component can accept a function as template and inject with `$element`.
[doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider)

> If template is a function, then it is injected with the following locals:
>
> - $element - Current element
> - $attrs - Current attributes object for the element

Therefore we could attach the main class for component (`.myComponent`) in the template function, then regex replace all the occurance of class names with compiled class names.

```
// utils.js
function decorateTemplate(template, styles, className) {
    return ['$element', $element => {
        $element.addClass(styles[className]);
        return template.replace(/\$\{(\w+)\}/g, (match, p1) => styles[p1]);
    }];
}

// my-component.js
import style from './my-component.css';
import template from './my-component.pug';
import { decorateTemplate } from 'shared/utils';

class MyComponent {
    // NO NEED to inject $element in constructor
    // constructor($element) { ...
}

angular.module(name, deps)
    .component('myComponent', {
        // decorate the template with styles
        template: decorateTemplate(template, styles, 'myComponent'),
    });

// my-component.pug, with special '${className}' notation
div(class="${fooBar}") FooBar
```

There are still one place to be improved that `decorateTemplate` uses regex replacement and template has to use a special notation `${className}` to specify the css-modules class names.

Any suggestions are welcome.

## UPDATE

I updated my `decorateTemplate()` function to leverage pug features, so that local class names can be written as `._localClassName`.

```
// utils.js
function decorateTemplate(template, styles, className) {

    return ['$element', ($element) => {
        $element.addClass(styles[className]);

        return template.replace(/\sclass="(.+?)"/g, (match, p1) => {
            let classes = p1.split(/\s+/);
            classes = classes.map(className => {
                if (className.startsWith('_')) {
                    let localClassName = className.slice(1);
                    if (styles[localClassName]) {
                        return styles[localClassName];
                    } else {
                        console.warn(`Warning: local class name ${className} not found`);
                        return className;
                    }

                } else {
                    return className;
                }
            });
            return ' class="' + classes.join(' ') + '"';
        });
    }];
}

// my-component.pug
._fooBar FooBar
```

Although this is much easier it does not eliminate the quirky notation (begin with `_` for local class names) and regex replace.

Any suggestions are welcome.